# AngularJS XHR in Mobile Safari spins network indicator forever

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, mobile-safari

I have a web app running across two subdomains, and all the calls work as they're supposed to. The problem is that when I make a cross-subdomain XmlHTTPRequest, in Mobile Safari the network indicator (in the status bar) spins forever, regardless of the request's success. If I make the request on my local subdomain, the indicator stops when the call returns.

I'm using AngularJS to do my XHR work. This code works as I expect:

```
$http( {method: "GET", url: "http://my.domain.com"} ).success (data) ->
    console.log "success " + data
.error (data, status) ->
    console.log status + " " + data
```

but if I do this:

```
$http( {method: "GET", url: "http://other.domain.com"} ).success (data) ->
```

then the network indicator spins forever. It seems to complete correctly in desktop Safari (as far as I can tell). Nothing in the Web Inspector indicates that any calls are pending - I can see the data returned, and my app receives all the callbacks. In Chrome (both iOS and desktop) the network indicator stops spinning as expected.

**Edit**

I filed a bug with Apple. They closed it for "insufficient information" but never asked for more information. I could repro with iOS 7 or 6.1, but in iOS 6.0 the network spinner stopped as expected. That strongly suggests it's an Apple bug.

I repro'd without Angular, as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log("ready state changed to " + xhr.readyState);
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            console.log("HTTP status " + xhr.status);
        }
    };
    xhr.open("get", "//my.domain.com", true);
    xhr.send();
</script>
```

Again, if the request is instead to `//other.domain.com`, where "other" is a different subdomain than where the script/HTML is hosted, then the network spinner runs forever.

Comment: It works correctly in iOS 6.0, but not 6.1. I filed a bug with Apple.

Comment: Any updates on this? Could you provide a link to the bug report?

Comment: I never filed it on Open Radar. They closed my bug for "insufficient information" but never asked for more information. Can you still repro? I haven't tried in a long time. The network indicator does the right thing in iOS 6.0 but spins forever in 6.1 or 7.0, IIRC.